# MapBox - using scale control in iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, mapbox

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/scale-control/

I've found this functionality on the Javascript Examples with MapBox. Just wondering if anyone has come across a way to do this with the Objective-C/iOS SDK version.

I tried using Legends in TileMill but with no luck, plus I'm not entirely sure that the Legends get exported when you export the MBTiles file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into these APIs:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/b83fc2ddf400b9e308fe0ccf87371f32b240d045/MapView/Map/RMMapView.h#L97-L100

You should be able to use that together with your map pixel size to determine a number.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I managed to use this combined with `map.scaledMetersPerPixel` in 
`- (void)afterMapZoom:(RMMapView *)map byUser:(BOOL)wasUserAction` to calculate scale based on my graphic size.